# Identifying the class of an object in a C# IList

Tags: c#, object, identifier

I have an IList variable which contains 1 - N entries of myObject.  Each entry can be an instance of myObject or any of it's child objects (derived class objects).  When doing a foreach over the IList, how can I identify which type of object each member of the IList is?

```
foreach(myObject anObject in myList)
{
   if(anObject is of type ???)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [is operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
foreach(MyObject anObject in myList)
{
   if(anObject is MyTypeWhichInheritsFromMyObject)
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of

`anObject is MyObject`

or

```
Type.IsSubclassOf(MyObject)
```

You can also make use of `baseType.IsAssignableFrom(type)` to determine if a type can be derived from a given base type

Comment: `Type.IsSubclassOf` expects a type as the parameter, not just any object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a .NET developer but in Java there's an operator called instanceof that will check if the object is an instance of a certain class.

Check this link out, it has to do with the typeid of an object, I think that's what you're looking for mate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2ay8610(vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask for the type of each instance do it like this:

```
foreach(myObject anObject in myList)
{
    Type anObjectType = anObject.GetType();
    // Perform appropriate work.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your OO structure is designed properly, you really shouldn't need to know - whatever you want to do with the object can be done using the appropriate implementation, regardless of which type it is.

With that said, you can get the type of any object by calling:

```
Type type = myObject.GetType();
```

And you can compare that type to another specific type, like:

```
if (myObject.GetType() == typeof(Foo))
```

The `is` operator can get you in trouble, depending on your scenario, since it will be true if you are checking if something is a parent class, even if it really is a child.  For example:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar : Foo {}

if (myObject is Foo)
```

This `if` will return true for either `Foo` or `Bar` objects.